# Why call addlink and setlink in WCF dataservices

Tags: wcf

Consider a customer has many orders.

```
context.AddLink(customer, "orders", order);
context.SetLink(order, "customer", customer);
```

The data store will be updated correctly with one or the other of these calls (after calling `SaveChanges`). So why bother calling both as is shown repeatedly in the documentation for WCF Data Services?

Answer (score 3):

You should call both since you have to manually set the links in both direction, unless you only need to save one of the links.

`context.AddLink(customer, "orders", order);` tells the context that there is a link from customers to your list of orders (order must be a collection).

`context.SetLink(order, "customer", customer);` tells the context that the order is connected to the customer. Then on `SaveChanges`, the links will be created in the database and you won't have referential problems.

You could also call `AddRelatedObject` instead, but it also calls `AddObject`, so the object can't already be in the context for this to work. [MSDN `AddRelatedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addrelatedobject.aspx)

Copied From [MSDN `SetLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.setlink.aspx)

```
// Add links for the one-to-many relationships.
context.AddLink(order, "Order_Details", newItem);
context.AddLink(selectedProduct, "Order_Details", newItem);

// Set reference links for the many-to-one relationships.
context.SetLink(newItem, "Order", order);
context.SetLink(newItem, "Product", selectedProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

for adding a ref in a "to-many" relationship (new order associated with a customer) call AddLink.  For the other way around ("to-one") call setlink.

Comment: Well, OK, but the question is why do both? As I stated in the original question the DataStore will be updated with the use of only one of the two methods. Yet, what passes for documentation often shows the use of both in succession.